# Why is VectorBuilder in the package scala.collections.immutable?

Tags: scala, collections

`VectorBuilder` is defined in the same source file as `Vector`. `Vector` is immutable and in the *scala.collections.immutable* package, so as a consequence the builder is in the same package.

As far as I can tell, `CanBuildFrom` uses a `VectorBuilder` as the default, if the return type is not explicitly typed.

- Is there a reason for not having the builder in a separate file in the mutable package?
- Is the builder not meant to be used directly? If so, which builder or buffer is to be used to create a `Seq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VectorBuilder` is not meant to be used directly. If you want to get a builder for a `Vector`, you only need to call `Vector.newBuilder[T]`, which returns a `Builder[T, Vector[T]]` (with the underlying instance being a `VectorBuilder`).

So if you want the default builder that would be used to create a `Seq`, you only need to call `Seq.newBuilder`:

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Seq.newBuilder[Int]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,Seq[Int]] = ListBuffer()

scala> Seq.newBuilder[Int].result
res2: Seq[Int] = List()
```

The above shows that the default implementation of `Seq` is list, and, logically, the default builder for a `Seq` is actually a `mutable.ListBuffer`.

`ListBuffer` is more than just a `List` builder, that's why it is in `collection.mutable` whereas `VectorBuilder` is not a `Buffer`, it cannot be used for anything else other than build a `Vector`. That's probably why it is defined locally in `Vector`. I am not sure why it isn't `private`, I cannot see it referenced anywhere in the public API of `Vector` itself. Maybe it should be (private).

---

Just for reference, there is no hidden magic happening with `CanBuildFrom`, it almost always just goes through the `newBuilder` above:

1. When you do not specify the expected collection type, as in `Seq(1,2).map(_+1)`, the only available `CanBuildFrom` [comes from](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L44) the companion object a `Seq`, and is of type `CanBuildFrom[Seq[_], T, Seq[T]]`. That means the result will be a `Seq` too.
2. Like most companion objects of collections, the `CanBuildFrom` instance `Seq` provides only does one thing: call `Seq.newBuilder` (that's defined in [GenTraversableFactory](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenTraversableFactory.scala#L44) ...)

That's why `CanBuildFrom` for `Vector` uses a `VectorBuilder`. For example, in this:

```
scala> Vector(1,2,3).map(_+1)
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(2, 3, 4)
```

The builder that was used is:

```
scala> implicitly[CanBuildFrom[Vector[Int], Int, Vector[Int]]].apply()
res13: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,Vector[Int]] = 
  scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@43efdf93
```

Comment: OK, there is a `newBuilder` method, and there is a difference between `Builder` and `Buffer. As there is another fine answer, I'll leave it open for some time; currently I cannot really say which one is better, thanks for your insight. But you've raised another question: Why is `Seq.newBuilder` not returning a `VectorBuilder`? It's not even returning a `Builder`, and it's even of a more sophisticated collection? But that feels like another question, so if you agree, I'd rather post another one.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you're suggesting that people use Seq.newBuilder, but does anyone do that? If I needed to build up a Map bit by bit, I think I'd use a mutable.Map and then .toMap, not MapBuilder. Rarely, I'll use CanBuildFrom in a special case. But maybe that's your point, you're taking the point of view of someone hooking into collections.

Comment: Someone was asking about MVx patterns, and I looked at my first scala code and found my newbie confusion over builder: https://github.com/som-snytt/House-of-Mirrors-Fork/blob/act/src/main/scala/hom/LightBox.scala#L356  I hope you find that as amusing as I do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mutable Vector.  By analogy to `ListSetBuilder`, the builder stays close to what it is building.

`mutable.StringBuilder` is anomalous because it is a frequently used type that is more first-class, and tends to get passed through API.  (It receives mention in the collections overview and doesn't require an import.  In fact, it plays a role in [this puzzler](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-027) because it is subtly different from the Java `StringBuilder` but you might forget that you're using it.)

`VectorBuilder` is public API.  The `newBuilder` on companion objects has more to do with the collection factory framework and `CanBuildFrom`.  Neither is mentioned [in the overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/creating-collections-from-scratch.html) where it explains how to make things.  I don't recall any snippets that suggest:

```
(ListBuffer.newBuilder[String] += "hello" += "world").result.toList
```

How you create a `Vector` depends on what you're doing, but the overview suggests the factory methods on the companion.  If you already have a collection (maybe non-strict), then `toVector`.  How do you make any collection of anything?

[This is a good Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928327/when-should-i-choose-vector-in-scala)  on choosing Vector over List for your Seq.

As an implementation detail, that `VectorPointer` thing you see in the scaladoc includes a big comment:

```
// USED BY BUILDER
```

Since `VectorPointer` is `private[immutable]`, builder must stay there as a practical matter.  That also suggests some thought was given as to what to expose as API.

In addition, `Vector` bears a similar comment:

```
// in principle, most members should be private. however, access privileges must
// be carefully chosen to not prevent method inlining
```

These comments suggest that access levels are not haphazard.

This question is an interesting opportunity to think about the design of the package.  It may be that Scala collections are a Rorschach inkblot test, revealing great beauty and symmetry, while at the same time, to the disturbed mind, a great imbalance in the universe. (Kind of kidding there.)

Comment: So the main points are: The `Builder` is close to what its building, one should use `Vector.newBuilder`, and access privileges are possibly chosen so that they do not prevent inlining. As there is another fine answer, I'll leave it open for some time; currently I cannot really say which one is better, thanks for your insight.

Comment: No, I buried my main point in the middle: you don't normally use a builder (see link to overview). If you need one (in a performance sensitive function), it doesn't much matter which way you obtain it: implicit CanBuildFrom, explicit by new or newBuilder. An interesting question, it turns out.