# Why is Seq.newBuilder returning a ListBuffer?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Looking at

```
val sb = Seq.newBuilder[Int]
println(sb.getClass.getName)
sb += 1
sb += 2
val s = sb.result()
println(s.getClass.getName)
```

the output is

> scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
>   scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

using Scala 2.10.1.

I would expect `Seq.newBuilder` to return a `VectorBuilder` for example. This is returned by `CanBuildFrom`, if the result is explicitly typed to a `Seq`:

```
def build[T, C <: Iterable[T]](x: T, y: T)
                              (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, C]): C = {
  val b = cbf()
  println(b.getClass.getName)
  b += x
  b += y
  b.result()
}

val s: Seq[Int] = build(1, 2)
println(s.getClass.getName) // scala.collection.immutable.Vector
```

in this case the builder is a `VectorBuilder`, and the result's class is a `Vector`.

So I explicitly wanted to build a `Seq`, but the result is a `List` which needs more RAM, according to [Scala collection memory footprint characteristics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320133/2390083).

So why does `Seq.newBuilder` return a `ListBuffer` which gives a `List` in the end?

Comment: Kind of a dupe of your http://stackoverflow.com/q/17599652/1296806, but I really didn't see what you had meant by your remark about CanBuildFrom. That's pretty funny. As an aside, I think maybe a question is a dupe if it elicits the same answers. Don't forget to read the overview doc and that Spiewak http://stackoverflow.com/a/6934116/1296806

Comment: @som-snytt If a `List` is the default implementation for `Seq`, then I would expect `CanBuildFrom` to return a `List` as well, if the result is typed to `Seq` (for consistency). I can add this comment now, because one of the answers stated the fact that `List` is the default for `Seq`. As for Spiewak's answer, I have read it before, but this raised yet another question: Both `Seq` and `List` are traits whereas `Vector` is not. But all I want is a `Seq` (`Iterable` with order), for example as the result of a method. The most efficient impl. should be used to fulfill the contract.

Comment: The notion of "most efficient" is contextual, so people argue about it. I think historically, Lisp types think in terms of List.  However,for CanBuildFrom, it clearly matters what you're building from, hence CanBuild *From*, so you're not off the hook there. But I see what you mean: you'd like to ask for a default CBF. Well, the default you get happens to be manufactured for a common use case, String, where you clearly want an indexed Seq.

Comment: I can't believe SO applies Twitterish length restrictions on comments.  Anyway: Why? I don't know. You could argue that Strings should be processed left to right; except that people assume string is backed by something arraylike. We do s.indexOf(c) all the time.

Comment: @som-snytt The context is the `Seq` trait. So I'd like to get the "most efficient" implementation for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Scala Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.package) is very complex and its hierarchy is rich in depth. Each level represents some sort of new abstraction. The `Seq` trait split up into two different subtraits, which give different guarantees for performance ([ref.](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Seq)):

1. An `IndexedSeq` provides fast random-access of elements and a fast length operation. One representative of this `IndexedSeq` is the `Vector`.
2. A `LinearSeq` provides fast access only to the first element via head, but also has a fast tail operation. One representative of this `LinearSeq` is the `List`.

As the current default implementation of a `Seq` is a `List`, `Seq.newBuilder` will return a `ListBuffer`. However, if you want to use a `Vector` you can either use `Vector.newBuilder[T]` or `IndexedSeq.newBuilder[T]`:

```
scala> scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq.newBuilder[Int]
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@1fb10a9f

scala> scala.collection.immutable.Vector.newBuilder[Int]
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@3efe9969
```

Comment: I was aware of the two sub traits, abut in fact I did not know that it is just that simple: The default implementation for a `Seq` is a `List`. I have just not seen that piece of information, because I looked at it only from the perspective of the `Seq` *trait*, but of course, yes, next time I'll look at the *companion* as well.

Answer (score 4):

The default `Seq` implementation is `List`:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)  // -> List(1, 2, 3)
```

...thus `ListBuffer` is the correct builder. If you want `Vector`, use `Vector.newBuilder` or `IndexedSeq.newBuilder`.

Comment: Yes, it's just that simple: It's clearly stated in the doc for the `Seq` *companion*, and I have only read the doc for the `Seq` trait.

Answer (score 1):

OK, but you're not going to believe it.  Turning on `-Yinfer-debug` for your `CanBuildFrom` counter-example,

```
[search] $line14.$read.$iw.$iw.build[scala.this.Int, Seq[scala.this.Int]](1, 2) with pt=generic.this.CanBuildFrom[scala.this.Nothing,scala.this.Int,Seq[scala.this.Int]] in module class $iw, eligible:
  fallbackStringCanBuildFrom: [T]=> generic.this.CanBuildFrom[String,T,immutable.this.IndexedSeq[T]]
[solve types] solving for T in ?T
inferExprInstance {
  tree      scala.this.Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[T]
  tree.tpe  generic.this.CanBuildFrom[String,T,immutable.this.IndexedSeq[T]]
  tparams   type T
  pt        generic.this.CanBuildFrom[scala.this.Nothing,scala.this.Int,Seq[scala.this.Int]]
  targs     scala.this.Int
  tvars     =?scala.this.Int
}
[search] considering no tparams (pt contains no tvars) trying generic.this.CanBuildFrom[String,scala.this.Int,immutable.this.IndexedSeq[scala.this.Int]] against pt=generic.this.CanBuildFrom[scala.this.Nothing,scala.this.Int,Seq[scala.this.Int]]
[success] found SearchResult(scala.this.Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[scala.this.Int], ) for pt generic.this.CanBuildFrom[scala.this.Nothing,scala.this.Int,Seq[scala.this.Int]]
[infer implicit] inferred SearchResult(scala.this.Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[scala.this.Int], )
```

and indeed,

```
  implicit def fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[T]: CanBuildFrom[String, T, immutable.IndexedSeq[T]] =
    new CanBuildFrom[String, T, immutable.IndexedSeq[T]] {
      def apply(from: String) = immutable.IndexedSeq.newBuilder[T]
      def apply() = immutable.IndexedSeq.newBuilder[T]
    }
```

What do you mean, your Iterable is not a String?

```
trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]
```

Such is the evil of inferring either Nothing or Any.

Edit: Sorry, I misspoke, I see that you told it Nothing explicitly.

Update:

Since CBF is contravariant in `From`, a CBF from `String` serves as a CBF from `Nothing`.

```
scala> typeOf[CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Int,Seq[Int]]] <:< typeOf[CanBuildFrom[String,Int,Seq[Int]]]
res0: Boolean = false

scala> typeOf[CanBuildFrom[String,Int,Seq[Int]]] <:< typeOf[CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Int,Seq[Int]]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

For instance, if you need to build from an `immutable.Map`, you'd want a CBF from `collection.Map` to work.

As someone else commented, it's just weird for `Nothing`.  But you get what you asked for. That is, you underspecified, which means you don't mind much what you get back, Vector or whatever.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, but I just fail to understand what you trying to show. Does it say that the resulting `IndexedSeq` is created by a `fallbackStringCanBuildFrom`? BTW I did learn about `-Yinfer-debug` to shine some light on the magic around CBF.

Comment: @Beryllium Yes! That might be obvious to some smarties, but not to me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is weird. Why don't you just use `Vector.newBuilder`, if that's what you're looking for?

```
scala> val sb = Vector.newBuilder[Int]
sb: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@1fb7482a

scala> println(sb.getClass.getName)
scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder

scala> sb += 1
res1: sb.type = scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@1fb7482a

scala> sb += 2
res2: sb.type = scala.collection.immutable.VectorBuilder@1fb7482a

scala> val s = sb.result()
s: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2)

scala> println(s.getClass.getName)
scala.collection.immutable.Vector
```

Comment: I am just looking for a `Seq` (`Iterable` with order), nothing more, nothing less. That's why I'd like to delegate the task of picking the best `Builder` and implementation class to the companion object generally speaking. Probably my question was not clear enough, the `VectorBuilder` was just an example of a possible alternative.