# How to set Vector to be the default implementation?

Tags: list, scala, vector

As I read in [When should I choose Vector in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928327/when-should-i-choose-vector-in-scala), the question, whether to use `List` or `Vector`, receives the same answer in Scala as in Java the question whether to use `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`. The answer, as you might know, is "use `Vector`/`ArrayList` in most cases".

However, in Scala `List` is the the ultimate default implementation of `Traversable` according to http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections. I guess it's not Vector because "it came late to the party".

1. Or is there another reason that `Vector` isn't more dominant?
2. Wouldn't it make sense to I set `IndexedSeq` to be the default implementation of `Seq` and therefore `Vector` to be the ultimate default implementation of `Traversable`?
3. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

`scala.mutable.Vector` based on [trie structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) so it's technically much more complex than `java.util.ArrayList`. This complexity means that bunch of `List`s sharing commong suffixes could be more lightweight than bunch of `Vector`s sharing common prefixes.

That property means a lot in functional style where you often have a lot of operations which take collection and return its copy modified just a bit, like [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). Appending to large `Vector` could generate several new objects, prepeding to `List` - always one.

`List` is very simple to understand and reason about. It's just `::` or `Nil`.

Implementation of `Vector` is pretty much hidden, it has [*"dirty"* optimisations](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala#L79) and could be matched preferredly via [seq extractors](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/SeqExtractors.scala) which refers to hidden optimized [drops](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala#L606)

Random haskell developer probably wants `Stream` to be default `Seq` instead of `List`. Some `scalaz` lover - wants [more some symmetric Sequence](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/#scalaz.IndSeq) exported to std lib.

You can not change choice of `scala.Seq.apply` becasuse it based on `List` as result of `ListBuffer` [chosen `newBuilder` implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L46). However you can  write your own similar `Seq` factory like

```
object Seq extends SeqFactory[Seq] {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Seq[A]] = ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]
  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = new VectorBuilder[A]
}
```

So summarizing:

1. Linked list is historically most dominant collection type in functional languages
2. Another sequence type could be much more useful in another domain
3. You can not "switch" `scala.Seq.apply` to another generic type. But can import or create another object under name `Seq`.

I personally find `Vector(...)` form more useful and concise than `IndexedSeq(...)`. Same for `List(...)` instead of `Seq(...)` or `LinearSeq(...)`.

Comment: Could you write three little numerated points summarising the answers for my three points? I (think) I get what you're saying (have to ponder about it a bit more), but are not sure what the actual answers are to my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The "use Vector in most cases" answer that you are used to in java, does not hold in scala, because it is a different language, with different patterns, tools and best practices.

Most structures and variables are immutable, and the algorithms are expressed most of the time in terms of sequentially processing streams of data. With these two observations in mind, one has to conclude that the collection implementation that would best fit most of the use cases is actually a linked list, not a random-access collection.

So, the short answer to your question #3 is "don't do it". A slightly longer version of it is: be explicit. If you think you want to use `IndexedSeq` in some place, just say so: `val seq = IndexedSeq(1,2,3)`