# Why do I get an error from this code?

Tags: clojure

I´m new to clojure and am trying to break through some of the walls I keep running into. The code in question is the function `v3` which should accept 4 arguments:

- a min and a max integer, `mi` and `ma`, to use with the
  `random-numbers` function to find numbers within a certain range,
- another integer,`cnt`, to signify how many numbers I want in my
  final list, and
- `tones`, which is a list of integers that the randomized numbers have
  to match once I've calculated modulo 12 of said numbers.

The function should run until `o` is a list of length `cnt` containing random numbers that are also in the `tones` list.

My document compiles just fine but when I want to run the function itself in a repl, for example using something like `(v3 58 52 15 '(0 2 4 5 7 9))` I get the following error:

`ClassCastException clojure.langLazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number clojure.langNumbers.reminder (Numbers.java:173)`

Here's my code

```
(defn random-numbers [start end n]
    (repeatedly n #(+ (rand-int (- end start)) start)))

(defn m12 [input]
    (mod input 12))

(defn in? [coll elm]  
    (some #(= elm %) coll))

(defn v3 [ma mi cnt tones]
    (let [o '()]
        (loop []
            (when(< (count o) cnt)
                (let [a (m12 (random-numbers mi ma 1))]
                    (if (in? tones a)
                        (conj o a)))))
        (println o)))
```

Comment: isn't this just that mod takes a number and you're giving it a sequence?

Comment: I guess that could be it, the random-numbers function might be returning a sequence of 1 number. I'll try that thanks :)

Comment: Such questions sit better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is more idiomatic Clojure to type the parentheses on the same line, and not in the "Java"-way.

When I debug your code I see it fails at the call to `m12`: `random-numbers` returns a sequence and the call to `mod` in `m12` expects a number.

You can fix this issue by for example taking the first element from the sequence returned by `random-numbers`:

```
(defn v3
  [ma mi cnt tones]
  (let [o '()]
    (loop []
      (when (< (count o) cnt)
        (let [a (m12 (first (random-numbers mi ma 1)))]
          (if (in? tones a)
            (conj o a)))))
    (println o)))
```

/edit

I am not sure what your code is supposed to be doing, but this did not stop me to make some more changes. If you use a [`loop`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop), you usually also see a `recur` to "recur" back to the loop target. Otherwise it does not do much. I added the following things:

1. a `recur` to the loop.
2. The `let` statement added to the `loop` vector (starting value).
3. `println` statements in the false clause of the `if`-statement.
4. Removed the first `if`-statement that checked the count
5. Changed list to vector. You would use a list over a vector when you [create code structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147975/in-clojure-when-should-i-use-a-vector-over-a-list-and-the-other-way-around#1148073) structure (for example [while writing macros](http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros/)).

See:

```
(defn v3
  [ma mi cnt tones]
  (loop [o []]
    (if (< (count o) cnt)
      (let [a (m12 (first (random-numbers mi ma 1)))]
        (if (in? tones a)
          (recur (conj o a))
          (println "a not in tones, o:" o)))
      (println "already " cnt "tones generated"))))
```

If you run `(v3 58 52 4 [0 2 4 5 7 9])` (note I changed your 15 for `cnt` to 4 and changed the list to a vector) a few times you get for example the following output:

> a not in tones, o: [4 4]
>   a not in tones, o: [9 5 5]
>   a not in tones, o: []
>   already  4 tones generated
>   a not in tones, o: [7]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll try to break out of my Java habits before the next time I ask for help. What do you see if you debug my code? It seems your comment may have ended prematurely.

edit: Never mind I can see the rest now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are trying to do.

This is an exercise in automatic composition. Your `v3` function is intended to generate a sequence of *tones*

- in a range given by `mi`n and `ma`x.
- with *tone class* drawn from a given set of tone classes (`tones`)

The `m12` function returns the tone class of a tone, so let's call it that:

```
(defn tone-class [tone]
  (mod tone 12))
```

While we're about it, I think your `random-number` function is easier to read if we add the numbers the other way round:

```
(defn random-number [start end]
  (+ start (rand-int (- end start))))
```

Notice that the possible values include `start` but not `end`, just as [the standard `range`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/range) does.

Apart from your various offences against clojure semantics, as described by [@Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476131/1562315), there is a problem with the algorithm underlying `v3`. Were we to repair it (we will), it would generate a sequence of *tone classes*, not tones. Interpreted as tones, these do not move beyond the base octave, however wide the specified tone range.

**A repaired `v3`**

```
(defn v3 [mi ma cnt tones]
  (let [tone-set (set tones)]
    (loop [o '()]
      (if (< (count o) cnt)
        (let [a (tone-class (random-number mi ma))]
          (recur (if (tone-set a) (conj o a) o)))
        o))))
```

- For a start, I've switched the order of `mi` and `ma` to conform with
  `range` and the like.
- We turn `tones` into a set, which therefore works as a
  membership function.
- Then we loop until the resulting sequence, `o`, is big enough.
- We return the result rather than print it.

Within the loop, we recur on the same `o` if the candidate `a` doesn't fit, but on `(conj o a)` if it does. Let's try it!

```
(v3 52 58 15 '(0 2 4 5 7 9))
;(4 5 9 7 7 5 7 7 9 7 5 7 4 9 7)
```

Notice that neither `0` nor `2` appears, though they are in `tones`. That's because the tone range 52 to 58 maps into tone class range 4 to 10.

Now let's accumulate tones instead of tone classes. We need to move conversion inside the test, replacing ...

```
        (let [a (tone-class (random-number mi ma))]
          (recur (if (tone-set a) (conj o a) o)))
```

... with ...

```
        (let [a (random-number mi ma)]
          (recur (if (tone-set (tone-class a)) (conj o a) o)))
```

This gives us, for example,

```
(v3 52 58 15 '(0 2 4 5 7 9))
;(53 52 52 52 55 55 55 53 52 55 53 57 52 53 57)
```

**An idiomatic `v3`**

An idiomatic version would use [the sequence library](http://clojure.org/reference/sequences#_the_seq_library):

```
(defn v3 [mi ma cnt tones]
  (let [tone-set (set tones)
        numbers (repeatedly #(random-number mi ma))
        in-tones (filter (comp tone-set tone-class) numbers)]
    (take cnt in-tones)))
```

This generates the sequence front first. Though you can't tell by looking at the outcome, the repaired version above generates it back to front.

**An alternative idiomatic `v3`**

Using the [`->>` threading macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) to capture the cascade of function calls:

```
(defn v3 [mi ma cnt tones]
  (->> (repeatedly #(random-number mi ma))
       (filter (comp (set tones) tone-class))
       (take cnt)))
```