# vectors vs lists with immutable data in Clojure

Tags: types, clojure, functional-programming, containers

I have written the same function twice, each using a list and a vector respectively. The function finds an element and returns the next one in the collection and wraps around if the found element is at the end. `nil` is returned if the element cannot be found.

### List version

```
(def syms '(\< \^ \> \v))

(defn next-elem- [coll elem]
  (loop [coll-rest coll]
    (cond
      (empty? coll-rest) nil
      (= (first coll-rest) elem) (nth coll-rest 1 (first coll))
      :else (recur (rest coll-rest)))))

(defn rotate-left [sym]
  (next-elem- syms sym))
```

### Vector version

```
(def syms [\< \^ \> \v])

(defn next-index- [coll i]
  (let [elem-count (count coll)]
    (cond
      (or (< i 0) (> i elem-count)) -1
      (= i (dec elem-count)) 0
      :else (inc i))))

(defn rotate-left [sym]
  (let [i (.indexOf syms sym)]
    (get syms (next-index- syms i) nil)))
```

#### Tests

```
(assert (= \< (rotate-left \v)))
(assert (= nil (rotate-left \o)))
```

Which version is better? I have read that lists are generally preferred in functional programming and at least in F# vectors (there arrays) are mutable, which is not what I need. Handling indices also feels awkward but is easier to wrap your head around as a non-functional programmer.

PS: This is one of the first functional programs I have written, so it might not be optimal.
PPS: Am I using the backslashes correctly or should I use something else in its place?

Comment: Clojure vectors are immutable. Also note that clojure lists are actually 64-ary trees under the hood. As for lists being better than vectors, it depends.

Comment: Aren't lists singly-linked lists?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147975/in-clojure-when-should-i-use-a-vector-over-a-list-and-the-other-way-around

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see, interesting. Though, that link from before mentions that lists are the equivalent of Java `LinkedList`

Comment: Clojure lists are indeed singly-linked lists. No trees are involved at all; they are very simple. Vectors are implemented as trees with a branching factor of 32.

Comment: @amalloy Really? I don't use plain lists that often, but I've been under the impression for awhile that they were trees. I'll have to look into the source. My bad. Deleting.

Comment: You can see for yourself just by looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentList.java): the only fields are `first`, `rest`, and `count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version of `next-elem-` is better because it would work with any sequence. Second version relies on sequence to have an efficient index access, which is really easy to accidentally fail and get a low-performing code.

An advice: change `rest` to `next`. Rest is sort of deprecated, next is better in all cases.

Also avoid using lists. They are very specific data structure, rarely needed. Whenever you need a linear sequence, consider vector first.

A functional version of your code:

```
(defn next-elem- [coll elem]
  (->> (concat coll [(first coll)])
       (drop-while #(not= % elem))
       (second)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am still thinking quite traditionally as evidenced by this cool implementation