# What do round brackets mean in the output of clojure.test failures?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, clojure.test

I have the following output in one of my tests:

```
Assertion failed:
Expected :[[] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] ["seq07"] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] []]
Actual   :[() () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () ("seq07") () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () ()]
```

What do `()` and `("seq07")` mean in this output?

Comment: clojure.org provide a page that explains and give names to each wired. So it should be easier to google about it. https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is a notation for list whereas `[]` is a notation for vectors

`()` is an empty list and `("seq07")` is a list that contains a single member - the string `seq07`

you can read more about clojure lists [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/list)

EDIT: just found this [interesting SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147975/in-clojure-when-should-i-use-a-vector-over-a-list-and-the-other-way-around) about lists vs vectors

Answer (score 3):

As noted in another answer, `()` is an empty list and `[]` is an empty vector.

Note however that `=` compares the contents of lists and vectors, it ignores the type of the container:

```clj
(= '("seq07") ["seq07"])           ;; => true
(= '(()) [[]])                     ;; => true
```

The assertion failure in the question is due to the `actual` vector having fewer elements than the `expected` vector:

```clj
(= ['("seq07")] ['("seq07") '()])  ;; => false
```