# What is a truly empty std::vector in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I've got a two vectors in class A that contain other class objects B and C. I know exactly how many elements these vectors are supposed to hold at maximum. In the initializer list of class A's constructor, I initialize these vectors to their max sizes (constants).

If I understand this correctly, I now have a vector of objects of class B that have been initialized using their default constructor. Right? When I wrote this code, I thought this was the only way to deal with things. However, I've since learned about `std::vector.reserve()` and I'd like to achieve something different.

I'd like to allocate memory for these vectors to grow as large as possible because adding to them is controlled by user-input, so I don't want frequent resizings. However, I iterate through this vector many, many times per second and I only currently work on objects I've flagged as "active". To have to check a boolean member of class B/C on every iteration is silly. I don't want these objects to even BE there for my iterators to see when I run through this list.

Is reserving the max space ahead of time and using `push_back` to add a new object to the vector a solution to this?

Comment: Have you determined that there is likely to be a performance problem, and that it is likely to be there?

Comment: @DavidThornley This isn't just a performance issue, it's a fundamental C++ issue. The default should be to never create invalid-but-existent objects. You don't have to measure the performance of going from "the wrong way" to "the right way" to justify the switch; you have to measure it to justify not switching.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `vector` has capacity and it has size. The capacity is the number of elements for which memory has been allocated. Size is the number of elements which are actually in the vector. A `vector` is empty when its size is 0. So, `size()` returns 0 and `empty()` returns `true`. That says nothing about the capacity of the `vector` at that point (that would depend on things like the number of insertions and erasures that have been done to the `vector` since it was created). `capacity()` will tell you the current capacity - that is the number of elements that the `vector` can hold before it will have to reallocate its internal storage in order to hold more.

So, when you construct a `vector`, it has a certain size and a certain capacity. A default-constructed `vector` will have a size of zero and an implementation-defined capacity. You can insert elements into the `vector` freely without worrying about whether the `vector` is large enough - up to `max_size()` - `max_size()` being the maximum capacity/size that a `vector` can have on that system (typically large enough not to worry about). Each time that you insert an item into the `vector`, if it has sufficient capacity, then no memory-allocation is going to be allocated to the `vector`. However, if inserting that element would exceed the capacity of the `vector`, then the `vector`'s memory is internally re-allocated so that it has enough capacity to hold the new element as well as an implementation-defined number of new elements (typically, the `vector` will probably double in capacity) and that element is inserted into the vector. This happens without you having to worry about increasing the `vector`'s capacity. And it happens in [constant amortized time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time), so you don't generally need to worry about it being a performance problem.

If you do find that you're adding to a `vector` often enough that many reallocations occur, and it's a performance problem, then you can call `reserve()` which will set the capacity to at least the given value. Typically, you'd do this when you have a very good idea of how many elements your `vector` is likely to hold. However, unless you know that it's going to a performance issue, then it's probably a bad idea. It's just going to complicate your code. And [constant amortized time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time) will generally be good enough to avoid performance issues.

You can also construct a `vector` with a given number of default-constructed elements as you mentioned, but unless you really want those elements, then that would be a bad idea. `vector` is supposed to make it so that you don't have to worry about reallocating the container when you insert elements into it (like you would have to with an array), and default-constructing elements in it for the purposes of allocating memory is defeating that. If you really want to do that, use `reserve()`. But again, don't bother with `reserve()` unless you're certain that it's going to improve performance. And as was pointed out in another answer, if you're inserting elements into the `vector` based on user input, then odds are that the time cost of the I/O will far exceed the time cost in reallocating memory for the `vector` on those relatively rare occasions when it runs out of capacity.

Capacity-related functions:

```
capacity()  // Returns the number of elements that the vector can hold
reserve()   // Sets the minimum capacity of the vector.
```

Size-related functions:

```
clear()  // Removes all elements from the vector.
empty()  // Returns true if the vector has no elements.
resize() // Changes the size of the vector.
size()  // Returns the number of items in the vector.
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. :) Learned a lot more than I directly asked for and that's why I love SO.

Comment: +1, but there is another reason to use `reserve`: iterators, references, and pointers to elements in a vector are invalidated if elements are inserted, *unless* you use `push_back` and `vec.size() < vec.capacity()`. So in some cases where you're adding elements in a loop and have iterators that you're holding on to, it can be useful to call `reserve()` first.

Comment: ^I just found out the hard way that this is also true for erase()

Comment: Generally speaking, any operation which alters a `vector` rather than an element in the `vector` could invalidate all iterators for that `vector`. So, it's generally a bad idea to alter a `vector` while iteratoring over it or needing to save any iterators to it. However, some operations - such as `erase()` - return a valid iterator to the next element, so it's possible to alter a `vector` in such situations and still have valid iterators, but you have to be careful with what you're doing or you can shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `reserve(n)` will allocate space without actually putting elements there - increasing `capacity()` without increasing `size()`.

BTW, if "adding to them is controlled by user-input" means that the user hits "insert X" and you insert X into the vector, you need not worry about the overhead of resizing.  Waiting for user input is many times slower than the [amortized constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) resizing performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, so let me try to answer what I think you asked.

Let's say you have a `vector<B>` which you default-construct. You then call `vec.reserve(100)`. Now, `vec` contains 0 elements. It's empty. `vec.empty()` returns `true` and `vec.size()` returns 0. Every time you call `push_back`, you will insert one element, and unless `vec` conatins 100 elements, there will be no reallocation.