# Data structure: insert, remove, contains, get random element, all at O(1)

Tags: data-structures

I was given this problem in an interview.  How would you have answered?

Design a data structure that offers the following operations in O(1) time:

- insert
- remove
- contains
- get random element

Comment: Can we assume additional restrictions on kind of data? like there are no duplicates, etc.

Comment: Sure, no duplicates, you can even use built in data structures in a language like java or c#.

Comment: I note that there's no specification re: ordered/unordered

Comment: I know this post has been answered however to me it would make more sense if they wanted you to provide o(1) random access as opposed to get a random element.

Comment: Did you find the correct solution for this ?

Comment: @ramsinb It would be useless since you can use any hash table like data structure from your language. Nothing to do. BTW it is useful if you need to get n random IDs without duplicate multiple times out of a set of fixed IDs.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Consider a data structure composed of a hashtable H and an array A. The hashtable keys are the elements in the data structure, and the values are their positions in the array.

1. insert(value): append the value to array and let i be its index in A. Set H[value]=i.
2. remove(value): We are going to replace the cell that contains value in A with the last element in A. let d be the last element in the array A at index m. let i be H[value], the index in the array of the value to be removed. Set A[i]=d, H[d]=i, decrease the size of the array by one, and remove value from H.
3. contains(value): return H.contains(value)
4. getRandomElement(): let r=random(current size of A). return A[r].

since the array needs to auto-increase in size, it's going to be amortize O(1) to add an element, but I guess that's OK.

Comment: This is close to what I had, but I missed the use of the elements themselves as the keys.... I knew I was close, but this really nails it on the head!

Comment: It's interesting that I got this question on a Google phone screen and after some struggling stuck to the same solution. I screwed up an implementation a little bit and assigned to the second phone screen.

Comment: APpend value to array : how is it O(1) ?

Comment: to know current size of array : How is it O(1) ?

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan i think it's a compromise that we have to make in this case

Comment: @aamadmi - well, in Java I guess it should. In pseudo-code, contains should work just fine :)

Comment: Why is array required, why can't we use hashmap.

Comment: I think this is correct, assuming you don't need to keep track of insertion order,  otherwise when we remove an item, the original insertion ordered is no longer kept since it seems we move the last inserted item in the array to the slot about to be emptied, if Im interpreting this correctly, which incidentally is why this solution works ...

Comment: @SamyVilar - So, if the question needs to keep the insertion order, this solution is not working, since it is not going to be O(1), because of the required shifting. right?

Comment: For adding a new element to the array, how can we know what the last empty slot is? How can we determine the last empty one, to put this new element?

Comment: There is hidden O(n) cost: once you delete some element from a hash table, everything inside the hash table will be rehashed which is O(n).

Comment: Cant we do this using HashSet of Java? It provides insert, del, search all in O(1) by default.
For getRandom we can make use of iterator of Set which anyways gives random behavior. We can just iterate first element from set without worrying about rest of the elements

Ex
public void getRandom(){
Iterator<integer> sitr = s.iterator();
Integer x = sitr.next(); 
return x;
}

Comment: @user1108687 Iterator of HashSet is not O(1) per iteration.  It's also not random.  It will return the same first entry every time until the hashmap changes.

Comment: @derek I don't think so. Why would a hash map need that ? To reduce space ? In that case, maybe it is also amortized.

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan, I guess it is the amortized time complexity we're talking about in this case for the addition of a single element to the vector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time (the answer that mentions the vector's append operation)

Answer (score 22):

O(1) lookup hints at a [hashed data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

By comparison:

- O(1) insert/delete with O(N) lookup implies a linked list.
- O(1) insert, O(N) delete, and O(N) lookup implies an array-backed list
- O(logN) insert/delete/lookup implies a tree or heap.

Comment: That is a start, but what about the last requirement?  Can you get a random element (with equal probability for each element in the data structure) from a hashed data structure?

Comment: @lag1980, I guess you can: `hashtable.get((int)(Math.random()*hashtable.size()));`

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know of any hashtables that let you get an element like that, and if there are any, I can't imagine that this would be a constant time operation.  I would be interested to be proven wrong on either count.

Comment: @lag1980 ...you could easily do it in constant time the same way Clojure's vectors are "constant time" -- log32(N) when the possible values of N are constrained by your hardware such that the largest possible log32() value is... something like 7, which is effectively constant time.

Comment: By "array-backed list" you mean: array?

Comment: Is it insertion O(1) in arrays?

Comment: @Hengameh **Setting** an element in an array is `O(1)`, but inserting into an array (moving elements down) is `O(n)`, as is appending to an array (which requires reallocation and copying). You can also have `O( log n )` lookup in an array using binary search if the array is sorted.

Comment: @Dai if we use vectors to append to an array, that wouldn't be  O(n),  right?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time (the answer on vectors)

Comment: @Payal That depends entirely on how the vector is implemented. Mathematically speaking, “vector” and “array” are synonymous. However in CS/SE “vector” colloquially refers to std::vector which uses an exponential growth allocation algorithm, while “arrays” have a fixed size (JavaScript’s Arrays have a lot of magic inside of them, it helps to ignore them in this context).

Answer (score 6):

For this Question i will use two Data Structure

- HashMap
- ArrayList / Array / Double LinkedList.

Steps :-

1. Insertion :- Check if X is already present in HashMap --Time complexity O(1) . if not Present Then Add in end of ArrayList -- Time complexity O(1).
   add it in HashMap also x as key and last Index as a value -- Time complexity O(1).
2. Remove :- Check if X is present in HashMap --Time complexity O(1). If present then find the its index and remove it from HashMap --Time complexity O(1). swap this element with last element in ArrayList and remove the last element --Time complexity O(1). Update the index of last Element in HashMap --Time complexity O(1).
3. GetRandom :- Generate Random number from 0 to last index of ArrayList . return the ArrayList element at random index generated --Time complexity O(1).
4. Search :- See in HashMap for x as a key. --Time complexity O(1).

Code :-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> al =new ArrayList<Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> mp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();  
        while(true){
            System.out.println("**menu**");
            System.out.println("1.insert");
            System.out.println("2.remove");
            System.out.println("3.search");
            System.out.println("4.rendom");
            int ch = sc.nextInt();
            switch(ch){
                case 1 : System.out.println("Enter the Element ");
                        int a = sc.nextInt();
                        if(mp.containsKey(a)){
                            System.out.println("Element is already present ");
                        }
                        else{
                            al.add(a);
                            mp.put(a, al.size()-1);

                        }
                        break;
                case 2 : System.out.println("Enter the Element Which u want to remove");
                        a = sc.nextInt();
                        if(mp.containsKey(a)){

                            int size = al.size();
                            int index = mp.get(a);

                            int last = al.get(size-1);
                            Collections.swap(al, index,  size-1);

                            al.remove(size-1);
                            mp.put(last, index);

                            System.out.println("Data Deleted");

                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Data Not found");
                        }
                        break;
                case 3 : System.out.println("Enter the Element to Search");
                        a = sc.nextInt();
                        if(mp.containsKey(a)){
                            System.out.println(mp.get(a));
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println("Data Not Found");
                        }
                        break;
                case 4 : Random rm = new Random();
                        int index = rm.nextInt(al.size());
                        System.out.println(al.get(index));
                        break;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

-- Time complexity O(1).
-- Space complexity O(N).

Answer (score 5):

You might not like this, because they're probably looking for a clever solution, but sometimes it pays to stick to your guns...  A **hash table already satisfies the requirements** - probably better overall than anything else will (albeit obviously in amortised constant time, and with different compromises to other solutions).

The requirement that's tricky is the "random element" selection: in a hash table, you would need to scan or probe for such an element.

For closed hashing / open addressing, the chance of any given bucket being occupied is `size() / capacity()`, but crucially this is typically kept in a constant multiplicative range by a hash-table implementation (e.g. the table may be kept larger than its current contents by say 1.2x to ~10x depending on performance/memory tuning).  This means on average we can expect to search 1.2 to 10 buckets - totally independent of the total size of the container; amortised O(1).

I can imagine two simple approaches (and a great many more fiddly ones):

- search linearly from a random bucket

  - consider empty/value-holding buckets ala "--AC-----B--D": you *can* say that the first "random" selection is fair even though it favours B, because B had no more probability of being favoured than the other elements, but if you're doing repeated "random" selections using the same values then clearly having B repeatedly favoured may be undesirable (nothing in the question demands even probabilities though)
- try random buckets repeatedly until you find a populated one

  - "only" capacity() / size() *average* buckets visited (as above) - but in practical terms more expensive because random number generation is relatively expensive, and infinitely bad if infinitely improbable worst-case behaviour...

    - a faster compromise would be to use a list of pre-generated random offsets from the initial randomly selected bucket, %-ing them into the bucket count

Not a great solution, but may still be a better overall compromise than the memory and performance overheads of maintaining a second index array at all times.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is probably the hash table + array, it's real fast and deterministic.

But the lowest rated answer (just use a hash table!) is actually great too!

- hash table with re-hashing, or new bucket selection (i.e. one element per bucket, no linked lists)
- getRandom() repeatedly tries to pick a random bucket until it's empty.
- as a fail-safe, maybe getRandom(), after N (number of elements) unsuccessful tries, picks a random index i in [0, N-1] and then goes through the hash table linearly and picks the #i-th element.

People might not like this because of "possible infinite loops", and I've seen very smart people have this reaction too, but it's wrong! Infinitely unlikely events just *don't* happen.

Assuming the good behavior of your pseudo-random source -- which is not hard to establish for this particular behavior -- and that hash tables are always at least 20% full, it's easy to see that:

It will *never* happen that getRandom() has to try more than 1000 times. Just *never*. Indeed, the probability of such an event is 0.8^1000, which is 10^-97 -- so we'd have to repeat it 10^88 times to have one chance in a billion of it ever happening once. Even if this program was running full-time on all computers of humankind until the Sun dies, this will *never* happen.

Comment: If you continuously choose to pick a random bucket that has value , how on earth is worst case lead to O(1) while you choose a random element

Comment: @user1147505 -  where did you get this number: "0.8^1000"?

Comment: How did you reach this: " hash tables are always at least 20% full "

Comment: Could you please write the method which you can pick a random bucket with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# solution to that problem I came up with a little while back when asked the same question.  It implements Add, Remove, Contains, and Random along with other standard .NET interfaces.  Not that you would ever need to implement it in such detail during an interview but it's nice to have a concrete solution to look at...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

/// <summary>
/// This class represents an unordered bag of items with the
/// the capability to get a random item.  All operations are O(1).
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the item.</typeparam>
public class Bag<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    private Dictionary<T, int> index;
    private List<T> items;
    private Random rand;
    private object syncRoot;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Bag&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Bag()
        : this(0)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Bag&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">The capacity.</param>
    public Bag(int capacity)
    {
        this.index = new Dictionary<T, int>(capacity);
        this.items = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Bag&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection.</param>
    public Bag(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        this.items = new List<T>(collection);
        this.index = this.items
            .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
            .ToDictionary(pair => pair.value, pair => pair.index);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get random item from bag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Random item from bag.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">
    /// The bag is empty.
    /// </exception>
    public T Random()
    {
        if (this.items.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (this.rand == null)
        {
            this.rand = new Random();
        }

        int randomIndex = this.rand.Next(0, this.items.Count);
        return this.items[randomIndex];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this.index.Add(item, this.items.Count);
        this.items.Add(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        // Replace index of value to remove with last item in values list
        int keyIndex = this.index[item];
        T lastItem = this.items[this.items.Count - 1];
        this.items[keyIndex] = lastItem;

        // Update index in dictionary for last item that was just moved
        this.index[lastItem] = keyIndex;

        // Remove old value
        this.index.Remove(item);
        this.items.RemoveAt(this.items.Count - 1);

        return true;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this.index.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.index.Clear();
        this.items.Clear();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.items.Count; }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this.items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var value in this.items)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        this.CopyTo(array as T[], index);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.syncRoot == null)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange<object>(
                    ref this.syncRoot,
                    new object(),
                    null);
            }

            return this.syncRoot;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that this will work if you have duplicate numbers.

Comment: It doesn't handle duplicates since @guildner said to assume there are no duplicates in the comments of the question. If a duplicate is added an `ArgumentException` with the message "An item with the same key has already been added." will be thrown (from the underlying index Dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

We can use hashing to support operations in Θ(1) time.

**insert(x)**
1) Check if x is already present by doing a hash map lookup.
2) If not present, then insert it at the end of the array.
3) Add in hash table also, x is added as key and last array index as index.

**remove(x)**
1) Check if x is present by doing a hash map lookup.
2) If present, then find its index and remove it from hash map.
3) Swap the last element with this element in array and remove the last element.
Swapping is done because the last element can be removed in O(1) time.
4) Update index of last element in hash map.

**getRandom()**
1) Generate a random number from 0 to last index.
2) Return the array element at the randomly generated index.

**search(x)**
Do a lookup for x in hash map.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is way old, but since there's no answer in C++, here's my two cents.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T> class bucket{
    int size;
    std::vector<T> v;
    std::unordered_map<T, int> m;
public:
    bucket(){
        size = 0;
        std::vector<T>* v = new std::vector<T>();
        std::unordered_map<T, int>* m = new std::unordered_map<T, int>();
    }
    void insert(const T& item){
        //prevent insertion of duplicates
        if(m.find(item) != m.end()){
            exit(-1);
        }
        v.push_back(item);
        m.emplace(item, size);
        size++;

    }
    void remove(const T& item){
        //exits if the item is not present in the list
        if(m[item] == -1){
            exit(-1);
        }else if(m.find(item) == m.end()){
            exit(-1);
        }

        int idx = m[item];
        m[v.back()] = idx;
        T itm = v[idx];
        v.insert(v.begin()+idx, v.back());
        v.erase(v.begin()+idx+1);
        v.insert(v.begin()+size, itm);
        v.erase(v.begin()+size);
        m[item] = -1;
        v.pop_back();
        size--;

    }

     T& getRandom(){
      int idx = rand()%size;
      return v[idx];

     }

     bool lookup(const T& item){
       if(m.find(item) == m.end()) return false;
       return true;

     }
    //method to check that remove has worked
    void print(){
        for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
            std::cout<<*it<<" ";
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a piece of client code to test the solution.

```
int main() {

    bucket<char>* b = new bucket<char>();
    b->insert('d');
    b->insert('k');
    b->insert('l');
    b->insert('h');
    b->insert('j');
    b->insert('z');
    b->insert('p');

    std::cout<<b->random()<<std::endl;
    b->print();
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    b->remove('h');
    b->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 3.0 + .NET Framework 4, a generic `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is even better than a Hashtable because you can use the `System.Linq` extension method `ElementAt()` to index into the underlying dynamic array where the `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` elements are stored :

```
using System.Linq;

Random _generator = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

Dictionary<string,object> _elements = new Dictionary<string,object>();

....

Public object GetRandom()
{
     return _elements.ElementAt(_generator.Next(_elements.Count)).Value;
}
```

However, as far as I know, a Hashtable (or its Dictionary progeny) is not a real solution to this problem because  Put() can only be amortized O(1) , not true O(1) , because it is O(N) at the dynamic resize boundary.

Is there a real solution to this problem ?  All I can think of is if you specify a Dictionary/Hashtable initial capacity an order of magnitude beyond what you anticipate ever needing, then you get O(1) operations because you never need to resize.

Comment: If you're very strict about what is a hash table, then O(N) resizing is unavoidable.  Some implementations compromise to reduce cost of resizing though - e.g., by retaining the existing table while adding a second of double the size, or trying to resize the existing table in place (after carefully arranging virtual address space and table sizes on page boundaries so no copying is required, which may require memory maps rather than new/malloc mem), then seeking in the new larger area before falling back on the smaller (in an in-place model by modding more tightly), with element migration logic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anon. Except for the last requirement where getting a random element with equal fairness is required all other requirements can be addressed only using a single Hash based DS. I will choose HashSet for this in Java. The modulo of hash code of an element will give me the index no of the underlying array in O(1) time. I can use that for add, remove and contains operations.

Answer (score 0):

Cant we do this using HashSet of Java? It provides insert, del, search all in O(1) by default.
For getRandom we can make use of iterator of Set which anyways gives random behavior. We can just iterate first element from set without worrying about rest of the elements

```
public void getRandom(){
    Iterator<integer> sitr = s.iterator();
    Integer x = sitr.next();    
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Java program to design a data structure that support folloiwng operations
   in Theta(n) time
   a) Insert
   b) Delete
   c) Search
   d) getRandom */
import java.util.*;

// class to represent the required data structure
class MyDS
{
   ArrayList<Integer> arr;   // A resizable array

   // A hash where keys are array elements and vlaues are
   // indexes in arr[]
   HashMap<Integer, Integer>  hash;

   // Constructor (creates arr[] and hash)
   public MyDS()
   {
       arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       hash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
   }

   // A Theta(1) function to add an element to MyDS
   // data structure
   void add(int x)
   {
      // If ekement is already present, then noting to do
      if (hash.get(x) != null)
          return;

      // Else put element at the end of arr[]
      int s = arr.size();
      arr.add(x);

      // And put in hash also
      hash.put(x, s);
   }

   // A Theta(1) function to remove an element from MyDS
   // data structure
   void remove(int x)
   {
       // Check if element is present
       Integer index = hash.get(x);
       if (index == null)
          return;

       // If present, then remove element from hash
       hash.remove(x);

       // Swap element with last element so that remove from
       // arr[] can be done in O(1) time
       int size = arr.size();
       Integer last = arr.get(size-1);
       Collections.swap(arr, index,  size-1);

       // Remove last element (This is O(1))
       arr.remove(size-1);

       // Update hash table for new index of last element
       hash.put(last, index);
    }

    // Returns a random element from MyDS
    int getRandom()
    {
       // Find a random index from 0 to size - 1
       Random rand = new Random();  // Choose a different seed
       int index = rand.nextInt(arr.size());

       // Return element at randomly picked index
       return arr.get(index);
    }

    // Returns index of element if element is present, otherwise null
    Integer search(int x)
    {
       return hash.get(x);
    }
}

// Driver class
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MyDS ds = new MyDS();
        ds.add(10);
        ds.add(20);
        ds.add(30);
        ds.add(40);
        System.out.println(ds.search(30));
        ds.remove(20);
        ds.add(50);
        System.out.println(ds.search(50));
        System.out.println(ds.getRandom());`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution properly handles duplicate values. You can:

- Insert the same element multiple times
- Remove a single instances of an element

To make this possible, we just need to keep a hash-set of indexes for each element.

```py
class RandomCollection:

    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}
        self.list = []

    def get_random_element(self):
        return random.choice(self.list)

    def insert(self, element):
        index = len(self.list)
        self.list.append(element)
        if element not in self.map:
            self.map[element] = set()
        self.map[element].add(index)

    def remove(self, element):
        if element not in self.map:
            raise Exception("Element not found", element)
        
        # pop any index in constant time
        index = self.map[element].pop()

        # find last element
        last_index = len(self.list) - 1
        last_element = self.list[last_index]

        # keep map updated, this also works when removing
        # the last element because add() does nothing
        self.map[last_element].add(index)
        self.map[last_element].remove(last_index)
        if len(self.map[element]) == 0:
            del self.map[element]

        # copy last element to index and delete last element
        self.list[index] = self.list[last_index]
        del self.list[last_index]

# Example usage:
c = RandomCollection()
times = 1_000_000
for i in range(times):
    c.insert("a")
    c.insert("b")
for i in range(times - 1):
    c.remove("a")
for i in range(times):
    c.remove("b")
print(c.list) # prints ['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question can be categorized into two cases : without duplicates and with duplicates :

//code without duplicates

```
 class MyDataStructure
{
public:
    // Initialize your data structure.
    unordered_map<int,int>mp;
    vector<int>v;
    MyDataStructure()
    {
       
    }
    // Insert element 'X'. Returns true if the element was not present, and false otherwise.
    bool insert(int x)
    {
         if(mp.find(x)==mp.end())
         {
            mp[x]=v.size(); 
            v.push_back(x);
            return true;   
         }
         return false;
    }

    // Removes element 'X', if present. Returns true if the element was present and false otherwise.
    bool remove(int x)
    {
         if(mp.find(x)!=mp.end())
         {
             int lastVal = v.back();
             int idx = mp[x]; //cuurent indx
             
             v[idx] = lastVal;
             mp[lastVal] = idx;
             v.pop_back();
             mp.erase(x);
             return true; 
 
         }
         return false;
    }

    // Search element 'X'. Returns true if the element was present, and false otherwise.
    bool search(int x)
    {
        if(mp.find(x)==mp.end())return false;
        return true;
    }

     
    int getRandom()
    {
            int randomIdx = rand() % v.size();
            return v[randomIdx];
    }
};
```

//with duplicates

```
class RandomizedCollection {
public:
    unordered_map<int,int>mp;
    vector<int>v;
    RandomizedCollection(){

    }
    bool insert(int x) {
       if(mp[x]==0)
         {
            mp[x]++; 
            v.push_back(x);
            return true;   
         }
         else if(mp[x]>0)
         {
            mp[x]++; 
            v.push_back(x);
            return false;   
         }
         return false;
    }

    bool remove(int x) {
         if(mp[x]>0)
         { 
             auto it = find(v.begin(),v.end(),x);
             v.erase(it);
             mp[x]--;
             return true; 
 
         }
         return false;
    }
    int getRandom() {
         int randomIdx = rand() % v.size();
         return v[randomIdx];
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Why  don't we use epoch%arraysize to find random element. Finding array size is O(n) but amortized complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score -3):

I think we can use doubly link list with hash table. key will be element and its associated value will be node in doubly linklist.

1. insert(H,E) :  insert node in doubly linklist and make entry as H[E]=node; O(1)
2. delete(H,E) : get node address by H(E), goto previous of this node and delete and make H(E) as NULL, so O(1)
3. contains(H,E) and getRandom(H) are obviuosly O(1)

Comment: This doesn't make sense.