# Efficient algorithm for random insertion and random query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am required to implement two operations below with performance constraints,

```
  /** insert a character, c at a given position, pos **/
    void insert(char c, int pos);

  /** return the current character at given position, pos **/
    char query(int pos);
```

Both of these functions can be called 10^8 times :(. Inserting new value at any position will change/increase all of positions of its right parts elements.

At first, I was thinking to implement with `Array` but that costs a lot in worst case `insert()`, because every time I need to shift right part of the array when I insert new value somewhere at the beginning of the Array.

Then I was thinking to implement with `Linked List`, but this has the same cost for `query()` function because, to get the actual value I must move forward/backword of the linked list.

I wonder if there is any well known algorithm or data structure which can be helpful in this situation.

*Update #1:*

Similar question was posted here ([Data structure: insert, remove, contains, get random element, all at O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682218/data-structure-insert-remove-contains-get-random-element-all-at-o1)) before,

but hash is not feasible for this problem because of frequent collisions when the value is of char type. There can be only 26 char in 10^8 positions. Also I don't need to solve in O(1) because this problem seems not solvable in O(1) by its nature. I want some trade of or hybrid solution where worst case of array and linkedlist will be minimized.

As @DAIe mentioned in comment I need some string like operations. Moreover, `insert to positio`n operation is not a hashtable operation at all.

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682218/data-structure-insert-remove-contains-get-random-element-all-at-o1

Comment: @thebenman the problem is different. Hash is not possible when the value is char type. moreover I don't need O(1) solution.

Comment: You certainly can use hash data structure with char data type. Also if you call it 10^8 times having `O(1)` can make significant improvements.

Comment: @thebenman, `insert to position` operation is not a hashtable operation at all

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, please, add to the question the clarification about where do you need to insert/query character

Comment: @DAIe I edited the question. I don't know why people are marking as duplicated.

Comment: The last question to clarify. Does insert operation to position `pos` change all positions of characters with positions `>= pos`? (Like in the string insert operation)

Comment: @DAle yes off course

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, that is the thing that is not clear from the question, and that's why hashtable comments appeared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [rope data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)). It is a balanced binary tree with leaf nodes containing short strings.

[image]

It has `O(log(n))` worst-case query operation and `O(log(n))` average time insert operation.