# A Data structure with delete o(1) and random access o(1)

Tags: data-structures

I was looking for a data structure with delete o(1) and random access o(1) for my project. Could anybody help ?

Comment: When you say "random access", do you mean access by key, or access by index?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682218/data-structure-insert-remove-contains-get-random-element-all-at-o1

Comment: You really need to add more context. Are you accessing by key or by index? Are your keys integers within a relatively small range, or variable-length strings, or something else entirely? How many items do you expect this data structure to contain? We need more information before we can provide anything like a reasonable answer.

Comment: By random access, I mean access by index of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on those complexities and you don't have to release memory in the table as soon as keys are deleted, then you can use dynamic perfect hashing.

It's a little complicated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing

To get O(1) deletes you'll have to defer any rehashes caused by delete until the next insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash tables with an average O(1) but worst case O(n)

Comment: Thanks. But I actually meant worst o(1)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-data-structure-that-supports-insert-delete-search-and-getrandom-in-constant-time/

Comment: I dont think you can find one that has worst o(1) for all purposes

Comment: @KristjanKica: yes,you can.Iff you have infinite memory!

Comment: You can make worst case O(logn) if you make balanced BST instead of linear chaining in hash table.