# Time Complexity for Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, arraylist, abstract-data-type

I found other entries for this question that dealt with specific methods, but nothing comprehensive. I'd like to verify my own understanding of the most often used methods of this data structure:

O(1) - Constant Time:

```
isEmpty()
add(x)
add(x, i)
set(x, i)
size()
get(i)
remove(i)
```

O(N) - Linear Time:

```
indexof(x)
clear()
remove(x)
remove(i)
```

Is this correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: think add(x, i) should be in second group, if I understand your question.

Comment: `remove(i)` is in both O(1) and O(N)

Comment: remove(i) is O(N) both in the worst case and in the average case, and O(1) in the best case (removing exactly the last element).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The best resource is straight from the [official API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

Comment: That does help, thanks. I see now why add(x, i) would run in linear time (worst case) because it may have to move a bunch of elements higher in the array to insert a new one. Same with remove(i). What's the difference between amortized constant time and regular constant time?

Comment: @dvanaria Some good answers about amortized constant time are at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time. Basically, the average time is constant, but each individual operation may take more time - in this case when the underlying array has to resize.