# time complexity for arraylist resizing java

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

I know that the default size for arraylist is 10, and that the arraylist automatically expands for additional items added.

What is the time complexity for the **resizing/expansion**?

is it similar to a normal array, where the items have to be copied over into the new larger array for O(n) time?

Comment: Reopened since this question specifically asks for `resize`, which the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540511/time-complexity-for-java-arraylist) did not answer. It also did not attempt to explain anything at all, it merely quoted that add/remove/... runs in O(n) but OP seems to already know that and is specifically asking for the resize operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

The time complexity for resizing is `O(n)`.

It will create a new array with **double the capacity** and copy over each element from the original array into the new array. This requires a **full iteration**. Note that this can be optimized internally by the JVM though.

---

### Amortized

Resizing is not needed *often*. In particular not for every `add` call. Hence, why it doubles the internal capacity. This gives room for a whole bunch of subsequent `add`-calls.

More formally, this yields the **amortized** complexity of `O(1)` for `add`, even though its regular complexity would be `O(n)` bound by the `resize`.

---

### Details

You can see the source of this [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L231-L241) (OpenJDK 17):

```
private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (/* ... */) {
        int newCapacity = ArraysSupport.newLength(oldCapacity,
                minCapacity - oldCapacity, /* minimum growth */
                oldCapacity >> 1           /* preferred growth */);
        return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The **preferred growth** is `oldCapacity >> 1`, i.e. double the capacity. The actual part that costs you performance and gives you the `O(n)` is `Arrays.copyOf(...)`.

This method is called primarily from [this helper](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L452-L457):

```java
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

That is used by the main entry point [`add(E)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L465-L469):

```java
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}
```