# Why can't you add items to arrays in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net

Why is it that within C# you can't add objects to an array unless you declare the length of the array or add the item straight away? For example I could not simply do this

```
foreach(object item in array)
{
   array.Add(item)
}
```

I would have to create a list and convert it to an array after the loop.

I do not want to know how to do, I want to have a logical explination of WHY arrays are fixed lengths but other collections aren't (List, ListArray)

Comment: Because you can't modify collection which you are enumerating in foreach loop

Comment: `Array` contains no method `Add` so you must be using a `List` like object already...

Comment: Isn't that just duplicating your array items?

Comment: This question start with the nonsensical assumption that arrays have an Add method.  You cannot reasonably expect an answer based on a nonsensical assumption.

Comment: Are you trying to populate an empty (but defined) array, or duplicate one already populated?

Comment: Sorry, I think I worded my question badly. I am asking why you can't populate an empty array in things SUCH AS a loop where as you can in other languages. I am questioning why Microsoft has not implemented a similar Add method.

Comment: Well if it's really an array, then it's because arrays can not grow. You have to pre-allocate them to the correct size. Tricks such as Array.Resize actually create a new array and copy the old array into the new one. You might be looking for `List<T>`.

Comment: @HelloWorld What would be the reason of first copying an array to a list and then convert it to an array again?

Comment: I am getting an object, then looking a certain property on the object that contains a dictionary of objects, I am looping through these item and adding them to a list because I can't add them directly to an array

Comment: 1 - Infinite loop, 2 - Array has fixed bounds, 3 - Cannot modify an enumerable while enumerating

Comment: Please read the updated question.

Comment: I added the answer to the updated question in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are not resizable because *that's how memory works*. Getting into how memory allocation works exactly in .NET is a little much for an SO answer, you can read all about it elsewhere if you want, but one aspect is basically universal across every platform: when you have a piece of memory allocated for something, the next address after that something might be part of some other thing.

So you can't just expand a piece of memory and hope nothing goes wrong, you'd have to test that you can expand it and have a plan B for when you can't - that plan B will be allocating a new block of memory, copying the old thing into it, and deallocating the old block.

To avoid reallocating and copying many times, it's common practice to make the new block twice as big as the old block, so if you add `n` items, you will only reallocate&copy `O(log n)` times, keeping the [amortized time for adding a new item to a dynamically-grown array down to O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102585/what-is-amortized-analysis-of-algorithms/11102874#11102874). So constant time, great - not really. It's still more time than if you didn't have to reallocate, and in fact even every `add` that *doesn't* cause a grow has a little overhead to make sure that no grow is necessary yet.

So, arrays that don't grow are a lot simpler, a little faster, and waste less memory. So in C# (and many other languages, such as Java and C++) you get to choose: do you want to use a growable "array-like-thing", or a non-growable one? There is a trade-off there, and these languages choose not to take that decision for you.

Comment: I actually like this answer very much, although it is not too helpful for someone who, as it appears to me, has still to understand some basics of programming. A little hint for those who are motivated by this to do some research: Look at the idea of [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9b9dty7d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)s and at the implementations of [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You'll find it all makes sense.

Comment: I know how arrays work.. It was just a poorly worded question that people misunderstood.

Comment: @HelloWorld it happens, I almost never word my questions such that other people understand what I'm trying to ask.. asking a question is harder than answering one :)

Comment: Oh a side note, thank you very much Harold that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

**Answer to the original  (before the answer was edited):**

Because a foreach loop does not dynamically change its end condition, while you are changing dynamically the object it is iterating over.

In your case (if it would be possible) it would never end, since in every loop one item is added to the array.

You can use a normal for loop for this:

```
int orgSize = array.Count
for (var i = 0; i < orgSize; i++)
{
    array.Add(array[i])
}
```

---

**Answer for the updated question: WHY arrays are fixed lengths but other collections aren't (List, ListArray):**

Arrays are fixed length probably because of historical reasons and keeping backward compatibility with C/C++. These 'normal' array don't have Add, Count, neither are they dynamic. Therefor it is much easier to use List/ListArray etc, although this come to a cost, like maybe some performance and in all cases more storage needed, because administration for the instantiation is needed.
However, if this is not an issue, I prefer to use List/ListArray/Dictionary kind of types because of the improved usability/features.

Comment: Adding an element to the same array where you are looping on? Not sure what the end result will be.

Comment: Probably an infinite loop, since you're using the length of the array as the loop condition...

Comment: @Everyone above: I fixed the problem.

Comment: @Joey: I think it is not a problem, using foreach is.

Comment: arrays don't have an add method on them :s?

Comment: Everyone has presumed that since you are using Add, that your `array` is a `List` (or even ArrayList eek)

Comment: @HelloWorld True ..thought you were using the Array type from the framework.

Comment: I still don't understand what this is supposed to achieve. There is no "Add" method, and no Count in Array - and why would you add an existing value to an array anyway? Could you please elaborate on the purpose here?

Comment: Also if you read the question correctly, you will see that I actually said you -can't- do that.

Comment: @Kjartan: I thought the Array type from the Framework was used ... and I also don't know the purpose of duplicating existing values ...I didn't make the question.

Comment: In that case there is a Count property and Add method.

Answer (score 4):

Because

1. Arrays are fixed in length from the time they are declared, you can neither add nor remove items. You can create a new array with greater length and copy from one to the other, but you cannot change the length of an array dynamically. You may want a `List<>` or some other collection type.
2. You can't change any collection while you're iterating over it (List, Dictionay, ArrayList etc), it's a limitation the language/library designers put in place. Allowing it would involve a huge amount of work, and would have performance implications that would hamper performance of **every** foreach loop, not just the ones where you change the collection while iterating.

So tl;dr you can't because *that's the way it's designed*

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is -sort- of what I was looking for.

Comment: @HelloWorld what *are* you looking for? A rationale for why arrays are fixed length?

Answer (score 3):

You could also just go the old fashioned route and use a for-loop. That doesn't know about the iterator- and collection change problems, and you don't need that temporary list thingy (seems rather inefficient).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have a fixed length. you can nevertheless use a loop to populate them if you know the required size beforehand:

```
var sourceArray = new string[100];
/* populate source */

var myArray = new string[sourceArray.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < sourceArray.Length; i++)
{
  myArray[i] = sourceArray[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your question is not clear, or does not quite make sense. If you're trying to populate an existing array (with a defined size, but no values), you could do something like this:

```
var myArray = new string[5];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
  myArray[i] = "Some value here..."; 
}
```

Adding existing items to the array itself makes no sense however.

Note: The `Add()` method exists for `List` etc., but there, it typicallye means "*Append this element to the end of my collection*".

An array has a defined length, which can not change, so you can not append to it - only change existing elements.