# Time Complexity of fitness function for GA

Tags: c#, time-complexity, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of my fitness function for the genetic algorithm I wrote.

What I did do: I already read a few articles and examples

- [How to calculate Time Complexity for a given algorithm](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nmallick/2010/03/30/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-for-a-given-algorithm/)
- [Big-O Complexity Chart](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)
- [Determining The Complexity Of Algorithm (The Basic Part)](https://philipstel.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/determining-the-complexity-of-an-algorithm-the-basic-part/)
- [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)
- [Time Complexity of Evolutionary Algorithms for
  Combinatorial Optimization: A Decade of Results](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~xin/papers/IJAC-V4N3-SS-8.pdf)
  .

However non of these were really satisfying, where I could say: Now I know how to apply this on my code.

Let me show you my fitness function, where I guessed a few execution times.

```
    public static List<double> calculateFitness(List<List<Point3d>> cF, Point3d startpoint)
    {
        List<double> Fitness = new List<double>(); // 1+1
        for (int i = 0; i < cF.Count; i++)  // 1 ; N+1 ; N
        {
            Point3d actual;  // N 
            Point3d next;  // N
            double distance;  // N 
            double totalDistance = startpoint.DistanceTo(cF[i][0]);  // (1+1+1+1)*N
            for (int j = 0; j < cF[i].Count - 1; j++)  // { 1 ; N ; N-1 }*N
            {
                actual = cF[i][j];  // (1+1)*(N-1)
                next = cF[i][j + 1];  // (1+1)*(N-1)

                distance = actual.DistanceTo(next);  // (1+1+1+1)*(N-1)
                totalDistance += distance;  // (1+1)*(N-1)
            }
            totalDistance += cF[i][cF[i].Count - 1].DistanceTo(startpoint);  // (1+1+1+1)*N
            Fitness.Add(totalDistance);  // N
        }
        return Fitness;  // 1
    }
```

Do you know any links where there are examples, so that I could learn how to calculate the time complexity use-oriented. 
Or maybe someone can explain it here. For example for this code piece I'm not sure at all: `double totalDistance = startpoint.DistanceTo(cF[i][0]);` --> (1+1)N ?
Or this: `actual = cF[i][j];` --> (1+1)*N*N ?

So in general, the time complexity would be: 1+1+ (1+N+1+N+N+N+N+4N+ N*{ 1+N+N-1+2*(N-1)+2*(N-1)+4*(N-1)+2*(N-1) } +4N+N) = 2 + (2+14N+ N*{12N-10}) = 12N^2 + 4N + 4 = O(N^2)

Comment: I found this book really good at explaining how to calculate the time complexity of algorithms.    https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844

Comment: It seems like that this book is in the library at our University. I will take a look at it. Thank you :)

Comment: Grab an advanced math book to go along with it you may need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when doing Big-O analysis, we ignore constant time operations (i.e. O(1)) and any constant factors. We are just trying to get a sense of how well the algorithm scales with *N*. What this means in practice is that we are looking for loops and non-constant time operations

With that in mind, I've copied your code below and then annotated certain points of interest.

```
public static List<double> calculateFitness(List<List<Point3d>> cF, Point3d startpoint)
{
    List<double> Fitness = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cF.Count; i++)  // 1.
    {
        Point3d actual;  // 2. 
        Point3d next; 
        double distance;  
        double totalDistance = startpoint.DistanceTo(cF[i][0]);  // 3.
        for (int j = 0; j < cF[i].Count - 1; j++)  // 4.
        {
            actual = cF[i][j];  // 5.
            next = cF[i][j + 1];

            distance = actual.DistanceTo(next);
            totalDistance += distance;
        }
        totalDistance += cF[i][cF[i].Count - 1].DistanceTo(startpoint);
        Fitness.Add(totalDistance); // 6.
    }
    return Fitness;
}
```

1. The `i` loop will execute *N* times where *N* is `cF.Count`. If we were being incredibly formal, we would say that the comparison `i < cF.Count` takes some constant time *c* and `i++` takes some constant time *d*. Since they are executed *N* times, the total time here is *cdN*. But as I mentioned, Big-O ignores these constant factors and so we say that it is O(*N*).
2. These declarations are constant time, O(1).
3. Indexing into a .NET `List` [is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346281(v=vs.110).aspx) as being O(1). I can't find documentation for the `DistanceTo` method, but I can't imagine it being anything but O(1) because it would be simple math operations.
4. Here we have another loop that executes *N* times. If we were being strict about it, we would introduce a second variable here because `cF[i].Count` isn't necessarily equal to `cF.Count`. I'm not going to be that strict.
5. Again, indexing into a list is O(1).
6. This is actually the tricky one. The `Add` method [is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

   > If Count is less than Capacity, this method is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

   - How this is typically implemented, the operation is O(1) most of the time, but is occasionally O(*n*) where *n* is the length of the list being added to, `Fitness` in this case. This is generally referred to as *[amortized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102585/what-is-amortized-analysis-of-algorithms)* O(1).

---

So in the end you mainly just have O(1) operations. What there is though is one O(*N*) loop within another O(*N*) loop. So the algorithm as a whole is O(*N*) * O(*N*) = O(*N<sup>2</sup>*).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time. Your answer really helped a lot. I actually know that when you do a Big-O analysis you have to ignore constant time operations. However I have to write a report about my genetic algorithm and I wanted the analysis to be complete. I can write about the time complexity only when I really understand it. The declarations within the for loop; isn't it executed N times? Because it is executed for every iteration? And would you mind taking another look on how I think the time complexity might be? I'm going to change it in my question block. I would really appreciate it.