# Confusion about time complexity of iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, time-complexity, language-lawyer

My source of confusion is the following paragraph in the C++ standard:

> All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized).
> Therefore, requirement tables and concept definitions for the iterators do not specify complexity.

- [[iterator.requirements.general] p13](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#13)

#### (1) Confusion regarding amortization

What does the *amortized* refer to in this context? *Amortization* requires multiple operations to be performed.

However, iterators have many uses that seemingly don't involve amortization.
For example:

```cpp
// let's say we know that the key is in the container, so we don't need .at()
return *my_container.find(key);
```

This example is dereferencing the iterator just once.
Can we reason about the complexity here at all? Where is the amortization?

#### (2) Confusion regarding operations

Time complexity refers to the number of operations performed. It is unclear to me what operations an iterator performs in this context.

Does each container specify what operations its iterator performs (the amount of which has to be amortized constant), or is this up to the reader's imagination?
For example, is it specified that `std::map`'s iterator traverses nodes or something?

---

Keep in mind this is a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) question.
References to the standard which clear up this confusion would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's imagine an `std::map::iterator` it's a LegacyBidirectionalIterator so it does `++`, `--` and `*`. Traversing the whole map using `++` is O(N) (you will visit each node up to three times?). But there is a bad O(log N) case e.g. moving from the rightmost leaf in the left subtree. Does that make sense? (but I don't think this is a complete answer)

Comment: amortized constant is weaker than constant. I think it is safe to assume that dereferencing is constant complexity.

Comment: I doubt that the standard spells out in details what they mean with "amortized complexity". Not sure if the `language-lawyer` tag makes sense here. For a non-standardese q&a there is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079327/amortized-complexity-in-laymans-terms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102585/what-is-amortized-analysis-of-algorithms

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm asking for references in the standard that would clarify a language technicality. That sounds like `language-lawyer` to me. I also suspect that the standard doesn't specify this anywhere, but maybe there is more information that I wasn't able to find. I think a lot of people assume that dereferencing is constant complexity, but ... well, I can't find any proof of that.

Comment: Amortized constant time does not require multiple operations to be performed. It requires that, if we were to draw a plot with `N` on the x-axis and total predicted time to perform a selected operation `N` times on the y-axis,  the plot will converge toward being linear with `N` as `N` gets large  (the "amortized constant" is the slope).   However, if we randomly pick just one sample, the time *it* takes may be much smaller or much larger than the average  (so worst-case execution time for that operation may be much larger than the amortized constant time, and best-case much better).

Comment: Is time complexity of iterators observable?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer complexity is specified in terms of the number of operations performed. For example, `std::sort` performs `O(n log n)` comparisons. So presumably *some* operation is performed by iterators too, which is the reference for the complexity. If it wasn't observable at all, then the standard also wouldn't specify it.

Comment: Invocations of comparison operation can be observable, I'm asking about observability of iterators

Comment: @LanguageLawyer in containers ... maybe no. Not sure. However, you can obviously create a `std::transform_view` or something with a custom lambda, and that lambda can contain observable behavior. The iterators of the view invoke the lambda. In that case, it would be important to know how many lambda invocations take place (as guaranteed by complexity requirements).

Answer (score 2):

#### What does the amortized refer to in this context?

About the same as any other context. In particular, that while the time taken to dereference an iterator may vary, it will tend toward a constant which is independent of the size of the collection.

In *most* typical cases, dereferencing an iterator will probably be constant time, not just amortized constant--but there have been (for one example) a couple of STL-like container collections (e.g., [STXXL](https://stxxl.org/)) that manage collections that are (at least mostly) stored in secondary storage. While I haven't looked at the internals of that specific one, it would certainly be reasonable for such a thing to maintain a cache of recently-used items in main memory. In such a case, dereferencing an iterator might involve only getting the item's current address in main memory, or it might involve reading it in from disk, then returning its address. The latter will typically be a few orders of magnitude slower than the former, but assuming the cache hit rate is approximately constant (at least for some access patterns), you get amortized constant complexity.

#### Does each container specify what operations its iterator performs (the amount of which has to be amortized constant), or is this up to the reader's imagination?

Each type of *iterator* specifies what operations it supports: at least `++` and `*`. Others may also support `--`, `-`, and `+`.

But you need to keep separate in your mind the operations on the iterator itself from the operations on the container that work with an iterator, return an iterator, etc.

Let's consider your example: `return *my_container.find(key);`.

A container that has a `.find()` member guarantees logarithmic complexity.
To find the correct node, the number of iterator assignments and dereferences are both limited to O(log N). But each of those operations on the iterator itself must have (amortized) constant complexity.

What happens inside the container as it does that search isn't specified directly. But in this case, we have a little more than imagination to guide us. There are only a few data structures that meet the requirement for logarithmic complexity for searching, insertion, and deletion, as well as (amortized) constant complexity for incrementing an iterator. It's pretty easy to conclude that `std::map`, `std::set`, `std::multimap` and `std::multiset` just about have to implemented as some variety of balanced tree to meet the complexity requirements. But no, that's not directly required--if another data structure can meet the same complexity requirements, it's allowed.

Comment: I have some doubts about your explanation of complexity here. The problem is that time, CPU load, memory usage etc. are all not observable in the scope of the C++ standard, so saying something like "this takes time" is completely meaningless. I think you're focusing too much on implementation details which give one a hint of what to expect, and what intent exists behind the wording, but ultimately don't answer the question about the C++ standard.

Comment: @JanSchultke: But that's all we can do--the standard simply does not specify more than (for example) that a particular operation has amortized constant complexity. As such, our only choices are to focus on the intent, or act as if "constant", "amortized constant" (and so on) have no meaning at all, because they're not defined in the C++ standard. If we decide to go the latter route, then we get into questions of "that depends on what the definition of "is" is", and the whole standard is meaningless.

Comment: @JanSchultke: As for your belief that I focus too much on implementations, I think that's also a mistake. I care about *understanding*. I could have (for example) simply said that the comment: "I think it is safe to assume that dereferencing is constant complexity" was wrong. But I'd rather point out a reasonable and feasible example of it being wrong, in the hope of imparting understanding rather than just repeating that the standard doesn't require that.