# Better method to increase the size of an array in C++ dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, realloc

Suppose I have a character array allocated with new.Now, if I want to modify the size of the array then which of the following two is the best method ?
1. using realloc function **OR** 
2.Allocate a new array, copy the data from old array to the new array and then delete the old array.

Comment: Neither, use `std::string`.

Comment: If you allocated an array with `new` (btw, you did mean `new[]` didn't you?) then don't use `realloc`. After all, you know what they say about randomly mixing different chemicals together, don't you? Think of memory management functions as chemicals. Just use `std::string`.

Comment: Out of those 2 terrible options, 2 is the only possible correct answer, as 1 is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate the block using malloc (not new) and then use realloc.  realloc knows how much free space is available after the block for expansion.

```
s2 = realloc(s,<size>);
if (s2) {
   s = s2;
}
else {
   free up s and handle the error
}
```

Most code I have seen doesn't correctly handle failure of realloc.

Comment: The block's address might change, `realloc` returns the new address of the block.

Answer (score 1):

You can't portably apply realloc to a buffer allocated with new. Hence only the second option of yours is viable.

Consider switching to std::vector and std::string.

Comment: Thanks, I know both are terrible options,but all I want to know is pure theoretical.

Comment: The second option is not terrible at all. It's just that we usually achieve our goals with much less sweat by relying on the library code. If you are developing your own collection library then doing as you propose in option #2 may be a perfectly good design decision.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are thinking about the whole matter from the C perspective.

if you are dealing with an array use a `vector`, it is dynamical and avoids the issues that you state in your question

e.g.

```
vector v(10); // allocates an array of 10 initialized to 0
v.push_back(42); // added another, so now array is 11 long
```

Answer (score 1):

The first option also implies copying if `realloc` finds that there is not enough free space after the block. (Even if you used `malloc` for allocating the array, which is the only correct option to use `realloc` at all.)

However, if you double the size of the array on each reallocation (or multiply its size by a constant > 1), the operation "increase array by one" uses *constant* time on average. Search for [Constant Amortized Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time).

Assume an array of initial size n. Reallocating to the new size 2n and copying costs 2n steps, but the next n "increase" operation are free.

By the way, this is how `std::vector` and many other array containers are implemented internally.