# Calculating complexity with stl vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, complexity-theory

I'm trying to calculate complexity of some algorithms but I don't no how to mesure the complexity of the operations with vectors. For example, what is the complexity of push_back()?

In c++ reference I found 
"Constant (amortized time, reallocation may happen).
If a reallocation happens, the reallocation is itself up to linear in the entire size."

What does it's means? Is the operation of complexity O(n)? (n is the vector length).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what "amortized" means?

Comment: Read the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=amortized+complexity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexities for vector are:

- push_back: O(1).
  Amortized stands for "rounded" because this complexity depend on a possibile reallocation.

You have reallocation when size of vector is greater than:

```
size_type capacity() const;
```

> **Returns:** The total number of elements that the vector can hold without
>   requiring reallocation.
>   **Notes:** Reallocation invalidates all the
>   references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the
>   sequence. It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during
>   insertions that happen after a call to reserve() until the time when
>   an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the size
>   specified in the most recent call to reserve().