# What is most straightforward aproach to have a Hash Map structure in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash

I know that the basic Map of C++  basically a Red Balck tree and therefore insertion and deletions takes O(log N). I intend to better performance with a Hash Table however I could not find bulit-in structure in C++ STD or even C++11 (rectify me if I am wrong). Now the question is how to acquire a way of Hash Table in C++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`boost::unordered_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html).

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> NumbersMap;
    NumbersMap numbers;
    numbers["1"]=1;
    numbers["2"]=2;
    numbers["13"]=13;
    numbers["100"]=100;

    BOOST_FOREACH( NumbersMap::value_type i, numbers) {
      std::cout << i.first << "," << i.second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would you provide a sample code how to call it since it has none at the reference page

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which was introduced in C++11. The complexity of accessing an element is average constant time.

Comment: `s/amortized/average/g`. Big subtle difference.

Comment: @delnan Is amortized not appropriate here? Is it just insertion and deletion that are amortized constant time?

Comment: Roughly speaking: [Amortized](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200384/395760) refers to the total cost of n operations, while average-case complexity refers to a single operation on an "average" data set. Two orthogonal things. To speak of amortized constant time would be to imply (1) *some* lookups in a *sequence* of operations take worse-than-constant time, and (2) the bound is unconditional/worst-case rather than requiring a "nice" data set.