# Why is std::vector::insert complexity linear (instead of being constant)?

Tags: c++, stl

Lets say I was inserting p new elements at the 'i' th position in an `std::vector<mytype>` of size 'n'.

Since items in `std::vector` are guaranteed to use contiguous storage locations for their elements, it seems like this would take me 4 steps to do the above:

1) Possible reallocation of the vector if we are out of space, basically doubling its size. But that is a constant time operation (albeit a very large one).

2) Next there is a memcpy of elements from index 0 through i-1 from the old vector into the new one.

3) Then you copy 'p' new items being inserted at ith index.

4) Then another memcpy for all items from i+1 through n indexes from the old vector to the new vector.

Aren't all the above constant time operations? Then shouldn't insertion itself be a constant time operation? Why then is `std::vector::insert` linear on the number of elements inserted (copy/move construction) plus the number of elements after position (moving)?

Comment: Re-allocation cost ought to increase with size.

Comment: If the underlying memory block is not fully used, there is no need for reallocation, but **you should shift n elements to the left to insert the new one.** (Thats done thorugh `memcpy()` and, as others noticed, its not O(1). `memcpy()`ing 4KB takes the same ammount of time as 3MB? Certainly not.)

Comment: Certainly not. The cost of `memcpy` is asymptotically proportional to the amount of data copied.

Comment: @user2672165, vector uses such an allocation policy that the cost of reallocactions is "amortized constant". What is amortized constant is well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time

Comment: Any implementation of std::vector that uses memcpy is fundamentally flawed. It doesn't call the constructors/destructors and assignment operators correctly.

Comment: @Andrey Chernyakhovskiy: The C++ Standard does not mandate that the vector class manage its memory in any particular way. What it does is to require that creating an n-element vector through repeated calls to push_back take no longer than O(n) time.

Comment: @josefx: You probably wanted to restrict that to not trivially copyable element types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Aren't all the above constant time operations?

No, the time complexity of `memcpy` and `memmove` is linear in the size of the block being copied or moved, because each of the `k` bytes being moved needs to be touched exactly once. The size of the block being moved is `sizeof(T) * N`, making the timing linear as well.

Even addition of an element at the end of a vector has linear complexity because of copying data on reallocation (however, adding `N` elements to the end of a vector has *amortized* linear complexity, which translates to amortized constant per-item complexity).

Comment: You mean, amortized *constant* complexity. Also, correcting the OP for non-trivially-complex types would be a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that there may be a possible reallocation then in that case time complexity will obviously be **linear** as mentioned in above answer. But even if there is no reallocation then also the time complexity will be **linear** as **vector::insert()** function has complexity of **O(n+m)** where **n is number of elements inserted** and **m is number of elements moved**.
Example: Suppose we insert one element in front of vector then all elements present in vector will be moved to right(that takes linear time) so the element can be inserted in front. Time complexity will be O(1 + elements_in_vector).