# HashMap vs. ArrayList insertion performance confusion

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

From my understanding a hashmap insertion is O(1) and for an arraylist the insertion is O(n) since for the hashmap the hashfunction computes the hashcode and index and inserts the entry and an array list does a comparison every time it enters a new element.

Comment: I assume, when you are inserting an element into array list using the method list.add(obj), its pretty straight forward.  It do in O(1) as it know what is the current size and it would like to insert at the end.  O(n) holds good when you try to insert using list.add(index, object) where it need swap n-index elements accordingly.  Its just my assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, an operation of complexity O(1) does not always take lesser time than an operation of complexity O(n). O(1) only means that the operation takes a constant time (which could be any value), regardless of the size of the input. O(n) means that the time required for the operation increases linearly with the size of the input. This means that O(1) is theoretically guaranteed to take lesser time than O(n) only when n is infinity.

Now coming to your examples, `ArrayList.add()` operation runs in amortized constant time, which means although it could take up to O(n) time for a particular iteration, the average complexity spread out over time is O(1). For more information on amortized constant time, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time) question.

Comment: The meaning of amortized O(1) time is that O(1), not O(n), is the average complexity spread out over time.  Individual operations can take O(n), but k add operations will take O(k) total time.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is faster than the `HashMap` when you add item at the last of the `ArrayList` because there is no need to shift the elements in the `ArrayList` to the right side, you can see the efficiency of the `HashMap` if you add an item at the front of the `ArrayList` like this `arrayList.add(0, str)`.

when check this use `1000` as outer loop instead of `100000` otherwise it may hang.