# For Array List resizing, why multiply a factor(for size of new array) makes it faster?

Tags: java, data-structures, computer-science

For adding element to an array list, the resizing part of the process，
why multiplying factor is much faster than just add a constant，the addition would create a very huge amount of memory box in total, hence its slow, but I suppose the multiplication method also creates a huge amount of memory box as well?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFWS1pGVn9w&list=PL8FaHk7qbOD7M1Zyio0exJXX9zMlG94Gk&index=8

```
    private void reSizing(int capacity){
        T[] a = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(items,0,a,0,size);
        items = a;
    }


    public void addLast(T x){
        if(size == items.length){
            reSizing(size*2);
        }
        items[size] = x;
        size = size + 1;
    }
```

the addition version of the code

```
    private void reSizing(int capacity){
        T[] a = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(items,0,a,0,size);
        items = a;
    }


    public void addLast(T x){
        if(size == items.length){
            reSizing(size + 1);
        }
        items[size] = x;
        size = size + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Well if you only add `1`, you will need to resize every single time a new object is added once you hit the limit the first time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41155632/1602555

Comment: Note that increasing by a factor 2 is not always a good thing, some solutions increase by a percentage, or have a maximum increase (because at a certain point, doubling size will increase memory pressure).