# reserve() function for Vector Of Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl, c++14

I am trying to populate a vector of string type and the memory for the strings will be updated periodically.I found out in a forum that, both of these processes consume a lot of time due to memory reallocation every time I update the size and I also read that the reserve function solves the problem pretty much for both the cases. -> [String](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) & [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)

My vector wont need more than 1024 slots and each string will need 10 character spaces.
I have reserved 1024 memory slots for my vector.

```
vector<string> power_set;
power_set.reserve(1024);
```

But is there any way to reserve the memory-slots for the strings that are inside the vector slots as well?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: There's a `reserve()` function for strings. So yes, you can iterate through the container and reserve enough space for each string.

Comment: Did you consider using `std::array<char, 10>` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: You actually might not need to call reserve on the string for 10 characters, because small string optimization does avoid the allocation.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't believe everything you read on a forum? `string` and `vector` doesn't reallocate memory *every time* you change the size. The reallocation happens infrequently enough to make it [amortized constant time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time). Also, 1024 is a number small enough that you will hardly ever notice any difference.

Comment: That makes sense @BoPersson .. thanks for the info .. then I guess I'm good to go without a reserve() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My vector wont need more than 1024 slots and **each string will need 10 character spaces**.

Then, consider the following (partial) definition of `MyString` class:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>   

class MyString {
    std::array<std::string::value_type, 10> str;

public:
// ...
};
```

By using `MyString` instead of `std::string`, when calling `reserve` on `std::vector`, the memory needed for the string contained in `MyString` (i.e.: `str`, which is a `std::array`) will be allocated:

```
vector<MyString> power_set;
power_set.reserve(1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reserve for strings. I'm not that experienced with vectors but you could make a custom class that allocates a certain numbers of characters for a string field and make of vector of that class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom allocator which would return an extra 10 bytes whenever asked - to ensure that only 1 allocation is done / string.  But I have to say this sounds a lot like premature optimisation.