# Reserving space for a double vector

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose `T` is a type, and I want to make a `vector<vector<T>>`. I know the eventual size will be `m x n`, where `m` and `n` are runtime constants. (If they were compile-time constants I'd use `std::array<std::array<T, n>, m>`.) Suppose I have three choices of what to do with my double vector before I continue with my program in earnest:

Option 1

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> dbl_vect(m);
for (auto & v : dbl_vect)
    v.reserve(n);
```

Option 2

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> dbl_vect;
dbl_vect.reserve(m);
```

Option 3

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> dbl_vect;
```

Let's suppose I am not worried about iterator & reference invalidation from vector reallocation, so we can remove that from the decision process.

Of course the code that follows these would have to be a little different, since #1 creates the (empty) rows of the dbl_vector, so we have to access the rows rather than pushing more back.

Option #2 seems fairly useless, because it has no idea how much space to reserve for each row.

Option #1 requires me to go through a linear pass of `m` empty vectors and resize them manually, but it prevents reallocation. If `T` were pretty big, this would almost certainly be preferable, I believe, because it would prevent copies/moves.

**Question:** Suppose `T = char` (or pick your favorite POD type). Under what circumstances should I be indifferent between options 1 and 3, or even prefer #3? Is this mostly due to the relatively small size of a `char`, or because of the way the compiler will (not) default-initialize a `char`? If `T` is larger, maybe user-defined, at what point (in size of the double vector or in size of `T`) should I start caring?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928547/vector-initialization-or-reserve/8928668) a somewhat similar question is asked, regarding one vector and `T=int`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using `reserve()` rather than just creating the `vector`s you want ?

Comment: @SidS Just so I'm clear, you mean creating them one-by-one and calling `push_back` as I go? That would likely mean reallocation, which may be worth avoiding.

Comment: @EricAuld: No, he means create them from an iterator so they have the values from the start.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh. I'm assuming my code is more complicated than that, so I don't know ahead of time what their values will be. (Imagine a situation where I'm writing code to return to me all the possible partitions of... you get the point)

Comment: #4 `std::vector<T> vec; vec.reserve(m * n);`

Comment: @Kerndog73 Yes, very good point. I deliberately did not include that because it seems obviously better. That might even make my question irrelevant.

Comment: I would do this allocation-initialization from the start: std::vector<std::vector<T>> dbl_vect(m, std::vector<T>(n));

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Why would that be better than #1? In your version I am calling T's default constructor m*n times but not using the result.

Comment: @EricAuld Of course it works best when T is a basic type (or any type with copy semantics such as pointers or smart pointers)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the inner size will be `m`, one possibility is to make a `std::vector<S>`, where `S` is your custom type standing for a `std::vector<T>`, except it knows how many entries it will have. A similar solution is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571928/8755792) (except there `m` is a compile-time constant).

Answer (score -2):

#3 just default-initializes the vector. There is nothing you gain from this, as the containing vector will have a capacity of zero. Dynamically allocating memory is slow, so to minimize this I would always go with #1 or a variant thereof.

Comment: I don't think that's true. It creates an empty outer vector and no inner vectors. (Option 3 wouldn't tell it how many inner vectors to create.) As opposed to 1 which actually creates the (empty, m) inner vectors, which will eventually have n entries. Not saying you're wrong in the big picture, but unless I'm mistaken, you're wrong about the initialization.

Comment: Yes. the containing vector has no elements, I should have expressed that more clearly

Comment: "...will in turn value-initialize or default-initialize...all of the contained vectors." That's what I'm saying option 3 will not do. None of the contained vectors will be created, only the single containing vector.