# unordered_map cbegin() + number //constant complexity?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, complexity-theory, unordered

As the title says, I know that cbegin() to an unordered_map has a constant complexity, but is the iteration of the iterator of constant complexity. e.g.: cbegin()++; cbegin() + 10; cbegin() + i; cend()--; 
Are all these o(1) ???

Comment: The iterators supplied by `std::unordered_map` are **forward iterators**. Forward iterators do not support addition: `cbegin()+10` and `cbegin()+i` are not valid. Forward iterators do not support decrement: `cend()--` is not valid.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is likely implemented as a hash table of pointers into a doubly linked list, and obviously that won't support random access iterators

Answer (score 1):

> 24.2.1 [iterator.requirements.general]
>
> All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are
>   realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized).
>   Therefore, requirement tables for the iterators do not have a complexity
>   column.

The first part of this might be slightly confusing, but all it says is that not all iterator types support all operations (i.e., no random access with forward iterators); but those functions that are defined, they always [have amortized constant complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time). The standard does not explicitly specify the complexity of each individual iterator method; it appears to indicate, in this clause, that those iterator methods that are defined must have amortized constant complexity.