# Complexity for new/alloc for method vector::push_back

Tags: c++

What is the complexity for alloc(realloc)/new operations for code below, for huge values of N.

As far as I understood push_back allocates memory:
size = cst*old_size;
cst = 2; // for gcc
So we have O(1) inside k cycle and ~O(N) inside i cycle.
In summary I have O(N), am I right?

```
std::vector<int> data;  
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)  
{  
    for (int k = 0; k < 2 * N; ++k)  
        data.push_back(k);  
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)  
        data.pop_back();  
}
```

Comment: The cost of the whole thing is O(n^2). This is because the inner loop is O(n) and the outer loop runs n times.

Comment: But the number of calls to operator new/delete (which will _not_ dominate the complexity calculations and so is kinda irrelevant) will be O(lg(n)) in the first run of the outer loop and none for subsequent runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reallocation happens, it doubles the allocated size of the vector so (for arbitrarily big values of N) in the given example, it will happen constant*log_2(N) times.

Yes, the complexity of the push_back call is amortized O(1) because reallocating does not take more time if the vector is big (better: the time does not depend on the size), but reallocation will still happen constant*log_2(N) times inside the loop (where constant != 0).

Finally, the complexity of reallocation in the k-loop example is O(log2(N)) and (edited) for the main loop, it's O(log2(N^2)) = O(2*log2(N)) = O(log2(N)).

Comment: (...) and not O(N*log2(N)) because it's the same vector!

Comment: Re: "it doubles the allocated size" -- the key is that it **multiplies** by some factor. Many implementations these days use 1.5 rather than 2. But that's a minor detail. +1.

Answer (score 4):

---

vector::push_back is not exactly O(1), but *amortized* O(1) which is required by C++ standard. See [Constant Amortized Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time)

Comment: Upped, much better than my soon-to-be-deleted answer.