# Amortized Runtime When Increasing Dynamic Array by Varying Sizes

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, append, amortized-analysis

I have a dynamic array that I am constantly appending items onto. An append is complexity `O(1)`. When the array becomes full, I would like to grow the array and copy it over, which is complexity `O(n)`.

Now, suppose I am growing the array at different rates when it becomes full. These rates are:

i) Some constant C

ii) n/2

iii) n^2

What is the amortized runtime in each of these scenarios?

I believe that I was able to solve case `i`. The amortized runtime will be the total cost of operations divided by the total number of operations. In this case, the total cost is `C * O(1) + 1 * O(n)`, and the total number of operations is `C`. Thus, the amortized runtime is `O(n)`.

However, I'm a little lost when analyzing the two remaining cases. It seems to me that the total number of operations will be `n/2 + 1` and `n^2 + 1`, respectively, but I don't quite know how to calculate the total cost of operations.

Can anyone lead me on the right path?

Comment: Looks like you're on the right path already.  ( O(n/2) + O(n) ) / (n/2) =....

Comment: @MattTimmermans With your comment and the other comment on this post, I was able to see the right path. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar analysis to the first case.

```
ii.
(n/2 * O(1) + O(n)) / (n/2) = O(1) + O(n)/n = O(1)
iii.
(n^2 * O(1) + O(n)) / (n^2) = O(1) + O(n)/n^2 = O(1)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249695/10987431) gives a more detailed explanation as to why a dynamic array that resizes in proportion to `n` (assuming it's resizing to `n` power of 1 or greater) has a constant amortized cost.

Comment: Great! The link you provided definitely did help me to gain a better understanding of amortized runtime.

It's interesting that increasing an array by n/2, n, and n^2 all result in O(1) amortized runtime. I see many people recommending that it's best to increase by 1.5n, so is this because such a growth rate is typically better for saving space in memory>

Comment: @T.Torline Although any growth rate proportional to `n` power of one or greater is O(1), big O notation doesn't take into account that the _actual_ constant value varies. `n/2` averages 3 operations, `2n` averages 1.5, and `n^2` averages 1. However, even though the average cost goes down the larger the growth rate, the unnecessary space used goes up. Plus, in a real-world scenario, you don't want the resizing (even if rare) to take forever. So the growth rate used usually depends on the use case and balancing compute/memory.

Comment: Ah, understood! It seems to be the case of "real-world vs. theory"! It certainly makes sense that we wouldn't want resizing to take forever (or take up a bunch of space in memory), which is why n^2 is not a commonly used growth rate.