# Why is std::map::erase(iterator it) amortized constant?

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase for reference.

How is erasing a single iterator able to be done in amortized constant time? This seems to imply that the rebalancing of the red black tree can be done in constant time.

Comment: It might not be balanced in constant time, but it can be balanced in _amortized_ constant time

Comment: Amortized constant time doesn't actually mean it could be done in constant time, rather there are certain part of the action was done in constant (`erase`), but other parts are not (rebalancing). For more, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time

Answer (score 2):

Amortized constant time doesn't mean that any single operation takes constant time, but that, over many such operations, the non-constant overhead of some operations amortizes to overall constant time.

In other words, if you use `erase` repeatedly to clear the entire map, that loop finishes in linear time in the number of elements, and thus constant time per element.

For a more thorough analysis, cs.stackexchange.com would probably be a more appropriate place.